# Angular marker clusterer does not refresh on marker hide

Tags: refresh, markerclusterer, angular-google-maps

I've created [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bdlgQENfaDTO7BknTqpc?p=preview) for showing this behavior, basically what I've done is to take the demo example from angular maps, and change it just a bit to hide 5 markers every time a marker on the map is clicked.
The markers are indeed hidden, but the clusterer never changes.  Now here is the strange part, if you drag the map a bit, it will update the clusterer correctly, but it does not refresh automatically.

The onclick event

```
$scope.clickHandler = function(e) {
    var count = $scope.randomMarkers.length;
    var hidden = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var oneModel = $scope.randomMarkers[i];
        if (oneModel.options.visible) {
           console.log("hiding: " + oneModel.latitude);
           oneModel.options.visible = false;
           hidden++;
           if (hidden == 5) break;
        }
    }
}
```

and the marker definition

```
var ret = {
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude,
    title: 'm' + i,
    events: {
      click: $scope.clickHandler
    },
    options: {
      visible: true
    }
  };
```

are the only real differences from the example (aside for telling the markers directive to actually use the marker model options property.